Is it possible to print two objects in parallel with the Ultimaker S5?
The Ultimaker S5 has two independent print heads and it is based (according to Cura) on the firmware Griffin. The firmware is not public.
Is there a way to use the two print heads in parallel, "duplicate" mode, so that I can print two identical objects at the same time?

The heads are not independent, it is one printhead assembly with 2 hotends

Indeed true, how could I miss that. I wonder what I was thinking :(

No, it's not possible to print two objects simultaneously. The printhead houses 2 hot ends called cores. They are not independent moving from each other as there is only one assembly. Furthermore, the second core is lifted when not used, if in use, it is activated by a lever on the printhead.

